# Buscar texto con mongo en varias colecciones referenciadasj

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express

Como mongodb no soporta join y tengo la necesidad de buscar en varias colecciones de negocios, servicios, y usuarios, he llegado a una solución pero necesito que sea validada y/o mejorada.

El flujo del esquema quedaria asi:

```
Business = Schema({
 name:String
 services:[{
  type:ObjectId,
  ref:'Services'
 }],
specialist:[{
  type:ObjectId,
  ref:'User'
 }]
})

User = Schema({
 full_name:String
 businesses:[{
  _id:{
   type:ObjectId,
   ref:'Business'
  },
  name:String,
  role:String,
  is_owner:Boolean
 }]
})

Service = Schema({
 name:String,
 specialist:[{
  type:ObjectId,
  ref:'User'
 }]
})

Search = Schema({
 text:{
  type:String,
  index:'text'
 }
 business:{
  _id:{
    type:ObjectId,
    ref:'Business'
   },
  name:String
 },
 services:[{
  _id:{
   type:ObjectId,
   ref:'Service'
  },
  name:
 }],
specialist:[{
  _id:{
   type:ObjectId,
   ref:'User'
  },
  full_name:
 }]
}
})
```

Los negocios ofrecen servicios, los servicios son realizados por los especialistas, y cada vez que un negocio agrega un especialista, el usuario tendra un nuevo negocio en sus datos con un role especifico.

La idea es que cuando se cree un negocio, se le cree un documento en Search, y cuando el negocio cree servicios los asigne a los especialistas, estos sean agregados a la coleccion Search. En cada modificación de ese documento se actualizara el campo text con un concatenación del nombre del negocio, servicios y especialistas, con esto tendrian una sola coleccion donde hacer las busquedas indexadas de texto. Cualquier campo que busque dara como resultado negocios.

Quien tiene sugerencias, tanto en modelo como en la solución de la coleccion comun para buscar.

Comment: MongoDB utiliza NoSQL, lo que significa : No hay relaciones, todo es una gran tabla por así decirlo. Si MongoDB es vital para tu app, sigue utilizándolo. Considera tener otra BD como MySQL, PostgreSQL ya que andas en la onda linuxera y servicios REST (que se comunicarán con dichas BD mencionadas) que te permitan mantener la misma arquitectura que estás usando.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente mongodb es una base de datos no relacional. Creo que lo que necesitas es usar Postgres o Mysql. Ahora MongoDB no ofrece join (por esa misma razón), pero podes usar aggregate para generar una especie de join. Mi opinion es que uses Postgresql y si queres tener algo de rápido acceso hagas una migración a MongoDB con esos datos.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor solución para seguir usando mongodb (debe ser mongodb), fue registrar los nombres de los servicios y especialistas en la coleción Business, crear indices de texto combinando los campos que necesitaba.

La unica consecuencia de esta solucion es que debo mantener actualizada la colección con los campos de texto pertenecientes a documentos de otras colecciones, pero es una solucián eficiente, ahora la consulta se realiza en una sola colección y no en 3.